# Symfony doctrine determine foreign Alias List is empty

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

In Symfony 1.4, Doctrine I have this snippet from schema.yml

```
Attendance:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    user_id: { type: integer(4) }

  relations:
    JoomlaUser: { class: JosUser, local: user_id, foreignAlias: AttendanceList }
```

and

```
JosUser:
  tableName: jos_users
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
  relations:
    AttendanceList: { class: Attendance, local: id, foreign: user_id }
```

What is the most efficient way to determine from JosUser that there are no Attendance records. I tried model/doctrine/JosUser.class.php

```
count($this->getAttendanceList())
```

but this returns a Doctrine Record with all fields empty but user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema :

```
JosUser:
    tableName: jos_users
    columns:
        id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    relations:
    AttendanceList: { type: many, class: Attendance, local: id, foreign: user_id }
```

With `type: many`, `getAttendanceList()` should return a Doctrine_Collection (see the JosUser base class in lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseJosUser.class.php), then you can use

`$this->getAttendanceList()->count()`

Comment: Thank you. This is the only relation in my schema, where I have it defined at both ends. I see now how that makes it look like a 1:1, whereas it is a 1:m